# Past simple or present perfect for the number of times of doing something

Tags: verbs, tenses

I have just called my friend on her cell but I couldn't reach her. Now I want to write her to inform her about it. Would you please tell me which one is correct?

" I **have called** you 3 times but I couldn't reach you.

Or

" I **called** you 3 times but I couldn't reach you."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Present perfect/Past simple - 2 structures which work differently?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288734/present-perfect-past-simple-2-structures-which-work-differently)

Answer (score 0):

> **Past simple or present perfect for the number of times of doing something.**
>
> I have just called my friend on her cell**,** but I couldn't reach
> her. Now I want to write her to inform her about it. Would you please
> tell me which one is correct?

" I have called you **three** times**,** but I couldn't reach you.

Or

" I called you **three** times**,** but I couldn't reach you."

COMMENTS:

The past perfect is better, but the simple past is fine. You can also say "*I've* called . . . ."

Since you didn't actually reach her, it would be more exact to say, "I've *tried* calling . . . ." or "I *tried* calling . . ."

NOTE:

Use commas to connect the clauses of compound sentences.

Comment: PS - Re "the number of times doing something": The number of times you called doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Why is the _past_ perfect "better"?

Answer (score 0):

If we consider to use present perfect for unfinished time and the calls were all made on the same day you're speaking, then present perfect would be better:

I have called you 3 times, but I couldn't reach you.